# Circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

This is not really about the topology of a circle it is about conflicting definitions of open sets in a circle $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\; 2}$....

- One definition says that there aren't internal points of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^{\; 2}$, because the neighborhoods are discs and those discs are including parts from outside of $C$ rather than being subsets.. so that means the circle isnt open.
- The other  definition is that a subset is open if it is an intersection with an open set of the ambient space. In thise case a person is telling me that $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{\; 2}$ is open because $C = C \cap \mathbb{R}^{\; 2}$. That ought to be true for all of the subsets of $C$ as well, but it conflicts with the former definition i gave.

Comment: There's a difference between being open in a topology and being open in a _relative_ topology.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that the notion of being open is a *relative* notion. Your first definition expresses that the subset of $C$ is open *as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$*, while the second says that the subset of $C$ is open *as a subset of $C$*. You are correct that those definition are not equivalent, and that's basically the point.

Comment: @fyaprsheaf No, the part of the circle with $y \ge 0$ is still not open, due to the fact that $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ (taking the unit circle) are not interior points in the relative topology. The part with $y>0$ is open, though. But also no singleton set is open in the circle, as the intersections of plane-open sets with $C$ cannot be single points (but are typically "open arcs" on $C$).

Comment: @fyaprsheaf arcs around $(1,0)$ contain points with $y<0$ as well, so that’s not an interior point and neither is $(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question could be raised about $ U=(-1,1)$ which is not closed in the standard topology of real line but it is closed in relative topology on $U$ because it is the intersection of $U\cap [-1,1]$

Comment: @fyaprsheaf  It is clopen in the relative topology but it is not closed in the standard topology of real line.